# How can I get the formula for this function?

Tags: calculus, functions

suppose $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ , And For any number given to it ,acts as follows.

Multiplies the number in itself and stores it . then removes the first and last quarters of the resulting number .

for example, $f(47)=20 $ because  $47^2 =2209 $ when we removes the first and last quarters of $2209 $ we have $20$.

I only work with two digit numbers.my domain. I mean  $\{x: 10 \leq x \leq 99\}$.

What is the formula for this function?

thanks

Comment: Remkve the 1st and last quarters of 100 and 10,000.

Comment: @ilen In other words, can you explain what you expect $f(10)$ to return and what you expect $f(100)$ to return ?

Comment: Hi @gandalf61 , $f(10)= 0$ , ( $10^2=100$).  and $f(100)=0$ . but I only work with two digit numbers. I edited my question too. Thanks again!

Comment: @ilen So for $10 \le x \le 31$ you want to keep just the tens digit of $x^2$ (because $x^2$ has only three digits), but for $32 \le x \le 99$ you want to keep the hundreds and the tens digit of $x^2$ (because $x^2$ has four digits) - is that right ?

Comment: @gandalf61 , Yes! That's precisely what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $\mathbb{A}$ be the set of all 2-digit numbers. Then as you indicated in the comments, we have $f:\mathbb{A}\to \mathbb{N}$. Note that $\forall x \in \mathbb{A}, 100\leq f(x) \lt 10000$.

Now, we note that for a 4-digit number, say $a$-

The first quarter is $a - ( \{ a/1000 \} \cdot 1000)$, where $\{ ...\} $ is the fractional part function.

Similarly, the last quarter is  $ 10. \{ a/10\} $.

Thus, $f(x) = x^2 - ( a - ( \{ a/1000\} . 1000)) -10. \{ a/10 \}$.

Comment: Hi @Devashish Kaushik , Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ilen My pleasure :)